# Excel Workbooks, and graphs

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2012, graph, interop

Hope this is not too tricky, however, I have been developing an application with C# and Visual Studio 2012 that parses out text and creates a series of `List<T>`'s. With that, I have successfully exported this data to an Excel spreadsheet. However, I have gotten as far as creating a graph on a new worksheet, however, I cannot figure out how to take the data, either from one of the lists, or from one of the other worksheets and graph it.

This is the snippet that I have been using for the graph creation:

```
const string topLeft = "A1";
const string bottomRight = "A4";
const string graphTitle = "License use";
const string xAxis = "Time";
const string yAxis = "Number of licenses";

var charts = worksheet.ChartObjects() as
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects;
var chartObject = charts.Add(60, 10, 300, 300) as
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject;
var chart = chartObject.Chart;

// Set chart range.
range = worksheet.get_Range(topLeft, bottomRight);
chart.SetSourceData(range);

// Set chart properties.
chart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
chart.ChartWizard(Source: range,
Title: graphTitle,
CategoryTitle: xAxis,
ValueTitle: yAxis);
```

If need be I can post the rest of the Excel document creation.

Answer (score 0):

If Interop is not required try using OpenXML SDK, you can create a template of the document you want to model it after, and use the OpenXML SDk tool to inspect the document and look at the code used to generate it, then factor that into the object you are trying to create. There is lots more information about it over at

http://openXMLDeveloper.org

and the DLL and tools can be found at

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425

There are several YouTube videos that demonstrate this as well. This solution will only work with documents that are OpenXML based (i.e. Office 2007 and later).

Answer (score 0):

Just created a simple example where you have company A B C and the number of licenses they have for 5 years.

you can see that you can select a worksheet by name and then add data to it and add a chart to it as well.

```
    Sheets excelSheets = workbook.Worksheets;
    string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
    Worksheet worksheet1 = (Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);
```

on the selected sheet you can add your chart, and tell it that you want the range from worksheet1, you can use any sheet's range and push it to that chart using SetSourceData hopefully this helps to answer your question about not figuring out how to " to take the data from one of the other worksheets and graph it. "

```
        var app = new Application();
        app.Visible = true;
        var workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);

        Sheets excelSheets = workbook.Worksheets;
        string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
        Worksheet worksheet1 = (Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);


        worksheet1.Cells[1, 1] = "";
        worksheet1.Cells[1, 2] = "Year 1";
        worksheet1.Cells[1, 3] = "Year 2";
        worksheet1.Cells[1, 4] = "Year 3";
        worksheet1.Cells[1, 5] = "Year 4";
        worksheet1.Cells[1, 6] = "Year 5";

        worksheet1.Cells[2, 1] = "Company A";
        worksheet1.Cells[2, 2] = "10";
        worksheet1.Cells[2, 3] = "50";
        worksheet1.Cells[2, 4] = "70";
        worksheet1.Cells[2, 5] = "70";
        worksheet1.Cells[2, 6] = "70";

        worksheet1.Cells[3, 1] = "Company B";
        worksheet1.Cells[3, 2] = "30";
        worksheet1.Cells[3, 3] = "70";
        worksheet1.Cells[3, 4] = "80";
        worksheet1.Cells[3, 5] = "80";
        worksheet1.Cells[3, 6] = "80";

        worksheet1.Cells[4, 1] = "Company C";
        worksheet1.Cells[4, 2] = "55";
        worksheet1.Cells[4, 3] = "65";
        worksheet1.Cells[4, 4] = "75";
        worksheet1.Cells[4, 5] = "75";
        worksheet1.Cells[4, 6] = "75";

        ChartObjects xlCharts = (ChartObjects)worksheet1.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        ChartObject myChart = (ChartObject) xlCharts.Add(60, 10, 300, 300);
        Range chartRange = worksheet1.get_Range("A1", "F4");

        Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
        chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLine;
```